# When does the Kazhdan-Lusztig polynomial $P_{x,w}(q)$ not vanish at $q=1$?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras, weyl-group, kazhdan-lusztig

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a semisimple Lie algebra and $\mathfrak{h}$ be a Cartan subalgebra. For any $\lambda\in \mathfrak{h}^{*}$ let $M(\lambda)$ and $L(\lambda)$ be  the Verma module and the simple module of highest weight $\lambda$, respectively.

Let $W$ be the weight group of $\mathfrak{g}$. For $w\in W$, the shifted action on $\mathfrak{h}^{*}$ is defined as $w\cdot \lambda:=w(\lambda+\rho)-\rho$, where $\rho$ is the half sum of all positive roots.

For $x,w\in W$ Kazhdan and Lusztig introduced the *Kazhdan-Lusztig polynomial* $P_{x,w}(q)$. The *Kazhdan-Lusztig conjecture*, which was proved in the 1980's, claims that
$$
\text{ch}(L(w\cdot (-2\rho)))=\sum_{x\leq w}(-1)^{l(x)-l(w)}P_{x,w}(1)\text{ch}(M(x\cdot (-2\rho))).
$$
where $\leq$ is the *Bruhat ordering* of elements in $W$.

Now it is clear that ch$(M(\lambda))$ appears in the linear combination of $\text{ch}(L(w\cdot (-2\rho)))$ only when $\lambda=x\cdot (-2\rho)$ for some $x\leq w$.

> > I want to know if there is an "iff" criterion. More precisely, for $x\leq w$, when do we have $P_{x,w}(1)\neq 0$?
> >
> > More generally, for arbitrary $L(\lambda)$, do we have an "iff" condition on which  $\text{ch}(M(\mu))$ appears in the linear combination of $\text{ch}(L(\lambda))$?

Comment: $x \le w$ if and only if $P_{x,w}(1) \ne 0$. Indeed, it is easy to see by induction that the constant term of $P_{x,w}$ is 1 if and only if $x \le w$, and the fact that they have positive coefficients then implies the result.

Comment: @GeordieWilliamson Oh, I see. How about the general case. We know that $\text{ch}(L(\lambda))=\sum_{\mu}m_{\lambda,\mu}\text{ch}(M(\mu))$ and the coefficient $m_{\lambda,\mu}\neq 0$ only if $ \mu\leq \lambda$ and $\mu=w\cdot \lambda$ for some $w\in W$. The strongly linkage gives more restrictions. Do we have some "iff" condition that $m_{\lambda,\mu}\neq 0$?

Answer (score 1):

For any weight $\lambda$, the multiplicities $m_{\lambda,\mu}$ are given by the Kazhdan-Lusztig polynomials of a Coxeter group called the  **integral Weyl group**, given by the elements $w$ such that $w\lambda-\lambda$ is in the root lattice.  So, by Geordie's observation above, we have that $m_{\lambda,\mu}\neq 0$ if and only if $\mu \leq \lambda$ in the sense that $\lambda-\mu$ is a positive element of the root lattice, and $\mu=w\cdot \lambda$ for some $w\in W$.